Connection for Hoover washer dryer drain pump
I am replacing the drain pump on my Hoover washer dryer and found that the electrical connection is not compatible with the new pump. In the old pump (top one in picture) the wires plug in with 1 connection. In the new one they are separate. Is there some sort of splitter I can buy to separate the connector I have to the 2 separate connections required for the new drain pump? Even just the name of this connection would be really helpful


Cut the wires and crimp on new individual connectors.

The 2-circuit connector is a RAST5 plug, 5 mm pitch.
The two single-circuit connectors are 1/4" quick-connect disconnects. (A.k.a. Fast-in, fast-on, and many other names.)
I haven't seen an adapter between the two.
The good news is that a RAST5 connector uses 1/4" quick-connect females as contacts. Therefore, if you can manage to extract the two contacts out of the RAST5 housing, they happen to be the correct female mates for the two single-circuit male connectors on the pump!
Try to figure out which line is Neutral and which is Line and connect them according to the L and N labels on the pump.

Note that quick-disconnects come in different sizes! These appear to both be the most common size, 0.250 inch, but there are also 0.110 inch and 0.187 inch sizes, and a few others that are less common.
